# listagem de dados

Tags: php, sql, foreach

ele só está imprimindo a primeira linha do banco de dados e quero que imprima todo as as linhas .

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/PlanejamentoEstrategico/model/indoperacionais/Indoperacionais.php';
?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><meta name="distribution" content="Private">
        <meta name="rating" content="Sistema">
        <meta name="copyright" content="UnimedMamanaus">
        <title>Planilha de Indicadores Operacionais</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">.texto {color:#006400;}
        </style>
        <center><h2><p class="texto">PAINEL DE INDICADORES OPERACIONAIS UNIMED MANAUS</p></h2></center>
        <body>
        <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;Formulario para Avaliacao Mensal - 2015 - 2016</h2>
        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;Area de Gestao de Pessoas</h3>
        <div class="sheet"></div>
        </div><center> 
       <style type="text/css">
       body {
    background-color: Very Light Grey ;
}
     h2 {
     border-width: medium;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: #FFFFFF;
     background-color: Very Light Grey  ;
     }
     h3 {
     border-width: medium;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: #DCDCDC;
     background-color: OliveDrab  ;
     }
     td {
         background-color: Silver   ;
     }
    tr {
         background-color: LightGray    ;
     }

       <div class='report'>

   </style>
  </head>
        <table border="2">
    <thead>

 <tr>
   <th>nome</th>
   <th>indicadores</th>
    <th>responvel</th>
    <th>metas</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<?php
    $ano        = $_POST["ano"];

    //Instanciando a classe
    $_model = new model_Indoperacionais();
    $_indoperacionais = $_model->RetornaIndoperacionais($ano);
     foreach($_indoperacionais as  $value){
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';

     }



    ?>


 </tr>
    </table>
    </thead>

            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



class model_Indoperacionais extends MysqlConnection{


    private $indoperacionais;

    public function RetornaIndoperacionais($ano){

   if($_POST["ano"] == '2016'){
        $_indoperacional = "/pla_est_2016";
    }else{
        $_indoperacional = "/pla_est";
    }

        $Query = ("SELECT nome,indicadores,responsavel,metas FROM `iniciativas`"); 


        //while ($_indoperacionais = mysql_fecth_array($Query));
        try{
            $this->search = $this->MySql->prepare($Query);
            $this->search->bindValue(":nome", $this->indoperacionais);
            $this->search->execute();

        } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        $_result = $this->search->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //print_r($_result); exit;
         return $_result ;
           //print_r($_result);
           //return (_result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor use o botão de [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/148436/edit) e indenti todo o código no icone `{}`. Seja bem vindo ao site, é interessante dá uma lida no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como funciona o site.

Comment: `fetch()` retornar apenas um registro ou vc usa `fetchAll()` ou usa `fetch()` com um while e no final retornar esse array.

Comment: sim , mas coloquei ele e apareceu assim nome indicadores responvel metas
Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array

Comment: Precisa especificar qual chave quer imprimir. ex `echo $value['nome'];`